# document.write() is throwing syntax error

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to add button using JavaScript, but instead of adding the button to the page, it is throwing an `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

```js
document.write('

<p>Sign in</p>
    <form action="/chat" method="GET">
      <p> Login: <input type="text" name="login"/> </p>
        <p>   Password: <input type="text" name="password"/> <input type="submit" value="Ok"> </p>
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="/signup">
        <button type = "submit"> button for registration</button>
    </form>');
```

Comment: Some basic JS syntax tutorials might be in order; that's not how you do multi-line strings. There will be other issues as well, but at least start with some language basics.

Answer (score 2):

Stay away from printing HTML that way please, but using ES6 [back ticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should fix this issue.

```js
document.write(`
    <p>Sign in</p>
    <form action="/chat" method="GET">
     <p> Login: <input type="text" name="login"/> </p>
     <p>   Password: <input type="text" name="password"/> <input type="submit" value="Ok"> </p>
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="/signup">
     <button type = "submit"> button for registration</button>
    </form>
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put enters in function code because interpreter thinks this is new line of code.
Check that:

```
document.write('<p>Sign in</p><form action="/chat" method="GET"><p> Login: <input type="text" name="login"/> </p><p>   Password: <input type="text" name="password"/> <input type="submit" value="Ok"> </p></form><br><form action="/signup"><button type = "submit"> button for registration</button</form>');
```